# MySQL Auto Export as .SQL Whenever Data Changed

Tags: export, backup, mysql

I am trying to Sync Local and Remote MySQL DB. I have Completed Remote Side Work and need an idea on how to Export MySQL DB locally whenever Database get Change. Any idea or existing Technique.

Comment: You should probably use MySQL replication to keep the databases in sync instead of exporting the database every time the data changes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Sync Between Local and Remote Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702556/mysql-sync-between-local-and-remote-server)

Comment: @hukir replicate i guess need access to remote db via ip etc and my host don't allow to access db remotely. Please tell if i am wrong, so i will continue my search with replication

Comment: If you can't access the server, how are you planning on transferring the file?

Comment: client side some how make a .sql, using winscp keep dir sync and it will upload file auto and after .sql uploaded run import script, that's it... its simple, i have written server side import script, just need to find a way to make auto export script.

Comment: are you fix your problem? same issue for me can you help?

Comment: @Karthi I didn't found good solution, however some of guys recommend me replication which i have not tried.

Comment: @Karthi today I was also searching for some local storage database, so I guess PouchDB can solve your issue. please try and let me know.

Comment: okay @WasimA. i going to try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "sync" between 2 MySQL servers not using replication, you can use the Percona Toolkit and you use the tool called "pt-table-sync". See here :

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html